# DB migration from Room DB to SQLITE

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have implemented Room DB earlier . Later I updated it to SQLITE with some column additions. Now I want to write migration for it. It will be a downgrade migration as Room is a wrapper class of Sqlite. Any help here will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To migrate from Room to SQLite you don't need to do anything as far as SQLite is concerned as the underlying database is an SQLite database.

However, if you have made schema changes (added columns) and then you want to utilise the changed SQLite database in Room then you will need to reflect those changes in the respective `@Entity` annotated classes (the tables).

It should be noted that Room is more restrictive/less flexible than SQLite and  it may require not only changing the `@Entity` annotated classes, bay may require conversion to suit the restrictive nature of Room.

As an example in SQLite you could have a column as   `thecolumn VARCHAR(50)`. Room only allows types that are INTEGER, TEXT, REAL, BLOB or null.

In the `@Entity` you would likely have `val theColumn: String?` (Kotlin).

In the above scenario, you could not simply utilise the SQLite database you would have to either:

- ALTER the table to DROP the column and then ALTER the table to ADD the column (being wary of the limitations of the SQLite [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) statement), or
- RENAME the table, then CREATE the table, preferable using the statement as copied from the generated java after successfully compiling the project with the respective changes made, and then populate the replacement (created) table with the data from the renamed original tale, which could then be dropped.

  - the latter method should cope better as the ALTER TABLE limitations would not apply.
  - the generated SQL can be found in the java (generated) folder (visible via the Android View), in the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with `_Impl`. In the class there will be a method `createAllTables` the SQL, per component, is EXACTLY as Room expects.

You may wish to have a look at [Changed data-type in room, how to do a migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023842/changed-data-type-in-room-how-to-do-a-migration/71025084#71025084), this utilises the second/latter method (i.e. RENAMEs the original table etc).